# C# Change the icon on the top left of winform

Tags: winforms, icons

I'm trying to change the top left corner icon of the winform from the default one to my icon:
[image]

I've tried it by going to the Properties of my project, and go into Application, the set my own icon it in "Icon and Manifest".

But after that, it still show the same old default icon. Is there something I done wrong?

Answer (score 72):

Your form has *properties* associated with it (in design mode, have the focus on your form and click *F4*). One of the properties is `Icon` and this is what you're looking for.

The icon you are referring to, in Application Properties, is the icon that will be used in the .EXE generated file.

Comment: @Coolguy there is a holo tickbox next to answers, if this helped solve your problem please consider marking it as correct :)

Comment: You can also change the text along the top of the pane from "My Program" in the image above to your title by changing the Text property

Comment: @Coolguy would you tick the tickbox next to my answer?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the icon setted for application using the following code:

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be a good answer for [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403169/get-application-icon-of-c-sharp-winforms-app)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy;
just right-click your window in the visual studio designer and click on settings then navigate in the settings sidebar to the icon section - click on the three dots and select a .ico file as your icon to be displayed in the top left corner of you application.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: Yes it does. It's an answer. Not a very good answer, but an answer. Downvote, don't flag.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that Photo you're choosing is .ico format then you can change simply change it in visual studio form properites.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before answering an old question ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).