# How to change the title icon of a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, titlebar

How do I change the title icon of a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Change the icon on the top left of winform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738312/c-sharp-change-the-icon-on-the-top-left-of-winform)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set it in two places:

- The *Icon:* dropdown in Project properties -> *Application*
- The *Icon* property of the main form (startup form).