# How can I export exe with custom icon?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe, publishing

I can already export a Visual Studio c# program to a single file exe. What I was curious about is if anyone knows of the console tag for adding a image to the exe or if I would have to do that in the properties beforehand. I tried in properties and it didn't work.

Comment: Your question has already an answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489497/how-to-change-the-title-icon-of-a-windows-forms-application

Comment: ^^^Not quite what I meant. I mean the single executable file u get when the project is published through the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From visual studio in the solution explorer right click on the project and select Properties. From Application tab in Resources grouping select an icon that icon will be applied to the executable file.[image: Properties page]

In addition if you would create a setup project and add shortcut to the desktop then you have to separately select an icon for the shortcut.
[image: Setup package]

Comment: will try this and see if it works; thanks for response.

Comment: Can't post image I guess but this worked! This is basically the same thing my professor told me when I asked him. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

## XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="WindowSample.MainWindow"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
    Title="WPF Window Sample" Height="350" Width="525"  
 Name="FirstWindow" Icon="Icon1.ico" >
```

I believe all you  have to do is add `Icon=""` to your `<Window>`

In this example the custom icon file is in the project folder, and its named "Icon1.ico".

- Note that the icon image file has to be a `.ico` file.
- Also note that the Icon file location can be changed to your preferences.

If you want even more help you should consider checking out [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/windows-icon-in-wpf/) article.

Comment: thanks I will check that out. Little different then what I intended though. I am not using WPF, win forms instead; guess I could have said that. Thanks for the answer though, I will try as I am prolly going to recreate program in WPF for practice.

Comment: @Virophage oh haha, I thought you already knew the original way to do it, and you needed a way to do it through xaml or something. Makes sense .