# vb.net add icon to form title bar

Tags: vb.net, icons, titlebar

This is a Visual studio 2019 WinForms project on a Windows 7 64 bit machine
I know how to use the Properties to add an icon but if the icon is to be embedded with the EXE file that is not the process to use. I have also created a folder named Resources and place the icon in the folder not sure that is the best idea based on the EXE might not include the folder

Here is what I have tried Right Click Project > Properties > Application > Icon ComboBox > Browse
Select the icon which is named s.ico and is 32 X 32
I also tried to cut and paste from the solution explore to the Debug folder BIG MISTAKE
Now I have no Release folder ?

**The question is this the correct process ?

Do I still need code to make this icon show on all the project forms ?**
One form does not have a title bar

OK I am adding to this Question
I created a test project with only a form. textbox and button
I added a icon to the button and it shows when the project is run
For some reason when I added the icon to the button a Resource Folder was created that contained the cat.ico I DID NOT CREATE the FOLDER( See New Screen Shot )

Now I followed the steps to add an icon to the titlebar NO LUCK 
Here is where I have no idea what is going on
If I right click on the two icon files One says the Build Action is "content"
If I right click on the other icon the Build Action is "None"
I see the option to select Build Action "Embedded Resource"
**Question What does Build Action do?

And if "Embedded Resource" is selected does that mean the file is included in the EXE?**

New Screen Shot
[image: New Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is a good way to solve the question
WHY because I do not understand how the code works BUT IT WORKS
Here is what I did I Right Click Project > Properties > Application > Icon ComboBox > Browse Select the icon
The icon in question is in the project > See the Screen Shot
Then I added this 7 year old code I found on SO
[Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738312/c-sharp-change-the-icon-on-the-top-left-of-winform)

```
Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath)
```

OK So now someone please explain how this works ?
Based on my limited knowledge I would say this will include the icon in the EXE file

Comment: Wow, 3 years and no one ever answered you?  When you apply that to a form (or any object for that matter) to you are telling the form to use the icon found in the main executable output. So if you set an icon for your projects main output (EXE) you use this to set all your forms to that same icon, assuming that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

(Project > Properties > Application > Icon ComboBox > Browse
Select the icon)

this indeed is the right way to select an icon for your project.

The icon will be found after that in your project folder not the debug folder.

After debugging your Project it will be embedded with it and the EXE file icon will be changed to the selected Icon.

No need to add it to the resources.

Finally, to set the same icon for all your forms, take a look at this topic:

[Set same icon for all my Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189031/set-same-icon-for-all-my-forms)

or of course, you could change it manually one by one in the (properties) menu, in (Icon), then browse to your Ico File.

Comment: I followed the steps and click RUN but none of the forms show an icon in the title bar any thoughts ? I do have the max control set to false on all forms and as I said one form has no title bar

Comment: If the ControlBox property of the Form is set to False the icon will not show. Change it from properties to True and the Icon Will Appear. Make Sure that in the Icon Property the New Selected icon is found not the word ((Icon) and default Icon Pic.

Comment: Also pay attention to the (FormBorderStyle) property. If (None) or (FixedToolWindow) or (SizableToolWindow) are selected, your icon will not appear

Comment: the name of the icon doesn't matter, it must be some updated settings you have done earlier, as a start describe your title bar image to me, is there an image of the default icon used by visual studio or no image at all??

Comment: So let's rewind a bit. Make a new project, follow the steps GME says. Do nothing else at all. Run the app. Do you see the icon in the title bar of the program(yes/no)? Do you see the icon in the windows taskbar(yes/no)?

Comment: I'm confused now. Earlier you said you were building an exe, now you seem to say you're not building an exe?

Comment: Pretty sure that when you do this route it is compile into the exe.. but now I'm not sure if you're asking about making the title bar icon, the taskbar icon, the exe icon and/or the icon when the exe is pinned to the task bar